# Processing Input

Tags: arduino-uno, programming

How to make an input from computer using processing (like a password form) and trigger pin in arduino?
If you let some link to read more that would be very helpful.

Comment: What part are you having problems with? Sending data to Arduino from Processing or parsing data on the Arduino? Your question is very vague. Read up on http://arduino.cc/en/reference/serial

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish in your project?  Please be more specific.

Comment: I want to enter a pass through processing and if its correct i want to trigger a pin.

Comment: Should it be the PC or the arduino which checks the password?  What happens if someone uses their own pc program instead of yours?

Comment: Arduino should have to contain the password

Comment: What have you done so far? Do you already have the PC-side app (with the password form)? How do you intend to connect the PC to your Arduino: serial/USB, or something else?

Comment: If you want the Arduino to contain the password, then a simple solution would be to put all the program logic there - generate a prompt, read input, check it, act on the result.  At that point the PC program can simply be any terminal emulator, written in processing or anything else.

Answer (score 3):

On the processing side you need to communicate with the arduino using the Serial class. To set up use something like the following. It is a bit of guess work 
to find which of the serial ports to use

```
Serial myPort;  
void setup() {
  // List all the available serial ports:
  println(Serial.list());

  // Open the port you are using at the rate you want:
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[6], 9600);
  myPort.buffer(2); // sets the size of the buffer, I send two bytes at a time
}
```

You can read a write using the `Serial.read()` and `Serial.write()` see https://processing.org/reference/libraries/serial/index.html for the processing serial references.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the Serial commands: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read

http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString